# How can I ref API gateway endpoint in serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am using `serverless.yml` as the infra. framework. I create a lambda with a API gateway like below code:

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: posts.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: posts/create
          method: post
          authorizer: xxx:xxx:Lambda-Name
```

it will generate a endpoint for the API gateway. But how can I reference this endpoint in other place in the `yml` file?

Comment: https://www.goingserverless.com/blog/how-do-i-get-my-api-gateway-url check if this helps.

Comment: It doesn't really help because it relay on an existing API gateway resources which is `ApiGatewayRestApi`. But in my serverless.yml file, there is no such resource. It is auto-generated by serverless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi` - ApiGatewayRestApi is a default Rest API logical ID.

[How do I get/reference API gateway restAPI id in serverless.yml?](https://forum.serverless.com/t/fixed-how-do-i-get-reference-api-gateway-restapi-id-in-serverless-yml/3397)

```yaml
custom:
    webServiceEndpoint:
        Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - 'https://'
            - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
            - '.execute-api.'
            - Ref: AWS::Region
            - '.amazonaws.com/'
            - ${self:provider.stage}
```

Comment: oh, is there a way to customise the id `ApiGatewayRestApi`?

Comment: provider:httpApi:id allows you to specify the id (line 169 in https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml )

Answer (score 0):

For socket endpoint you can use. Also check your cloudformation in .serverless to recheck these names.

```
socketServiceEndpoint:
Fn::Join:
  - ""
  - - "wss://"
    - Ref: WebsocketsApi 
    - ".execute-api."
    - Ref: AWS::Region
    - ".amazonaws.com/"
    - ${self:provider.stage}
```